# How do I make a base GUI function which uses any pane

Tags: java, javafx

I have been working with JavaFX and was wondering if I could make a base GUI function which takes any pane as a parameter i.e., not just a VBox.

I can have multiple functions which take in a border pane or HBox or tilepane but I don't want multiple functions just one. I even tried casting the pane to a node but didn't work.

Here is where I use it

```java
private void menu()
{
    VBox root = new VBox();
    Label title = new Label("Quiz");
    title.setStyle("-fx-font-size: 18px; -fx-font-weight: bold;");
    Button btnQuiz = new Button("Quiz");
    btnQuiz.setOnAction(event -> quiz());
    btnQuiz.setMaxWidth(75);
    Button btnCreate = new Button("Create");
    btnCreate.setOnAction(event -> create());
    btnCreate.setMaxWidth(75);
    Button btnQuit = new Button("Quit");
    btnQuit.setOnAction(event -> System.exit(0));
    btnQuit.setMaxWidth(75);
    baseGUI(root, title, btnQuiz, btnCreate, btnQuit);
}
```

Here is the baseGUI code

```java
private void baseGUI(VBox root, Node... nodes)
{
    for (Node node : nodes)
    {
        root.getChildren().add(node);
    }
    root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    root.setSpacing(10.00);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 250);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

In the end, I should have one function which takes in a root parameter that can handle any type of pane, and another Node of nodes. Thanks for any help.

Comment: So why can't you use `private void baseGui (Pane pane, Node... nodes)`?

Comment: oops didn't think of that also you cannot use setAlignment and set spacing

Comment: You can configure your `Pane` (whether it's a `VBox`, `HBox`, etc) before passing it to the `baseGUI()` method.

Comment: I have, I'll update the question.

Comment: Right, so you need to set the alignment and spacing *before* calling `baseGUI()`. Not all layouts that extend `Pane` have alignment or spacing properties. For example, there is no "spacing" property for a `TilePane`, so what would you expect `setSpacing()` to do if you pass a `TilePane` through? So if you intend to use a `VBox`, you need to set those properties first.

Comment: Ok I see but I would have to do that for every new GUI that I create just wondering if there was an easy solution

Comment: You can use  [`Parent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html) for the root GUI layout nodes.

Comment: `Parent` doesn't provide write access to the child list though (`getChildren` is `protected`)... As for the loop: `ObservableList<T>` provides an `addAll(T...)` method allowing you to get rid of the loop: `root.getChildren().addAll(nodes);`

Comment: as far as I can see it is not possible then

Comment: As mentioned by Zephyr, the `spacing` part doesn't make sense for `Pane`s other than `VBox` and `HBox`. You'll inevitably have to threat this kind of functionality seperately, but you can do this without repeating all the logic: simply do the custom treatment of the node type seperately and then invoke a `baseGui(Pane pane, Node... nodes)` method to do the common logic. Btw: It's hard to tell, what exactly you're trying to achieve here. How would you expect such a method, if it were possible to implement this, deal with e.g. a `GridPane`?

Comment: Ok thanks for the help I was just looking into it really and when pane is used you cannot do set Alignment too

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to this in the end but thanks for anyone that helped

```java
/**
 * baseGUI function
 * Creates a baseGUI function
 * @param root
 * @param nodes
 */
private void baseGUI(Pane root, Node... nodes)
{
    if (root instanceof VBox)
    {
        ((VBox) root).setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        ((VBox) root).setSpacing(10);
        ((VBox)root).getChildren().add(nodes);
    }
    root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 250, 250);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

For future reference, this is a base GUI function that takes in nodes as a parameter and a pane and outputs to the screen.

#### Update:

Changed method so it now works for any pane

Comment: Why not have another method (e.g. `vboxGUI`) that accepts the `VBox`, configures the `VBox`-specific properties, and then calls `baseGUI` at the end? Using `instanceof` as you are will become impractical if you need to handle objects other than `VBox` as well.

Comment: Also, as [mentioned by fabian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56818435/how-do-i-make-a-base-gui-function-which-uses-any-pane#comment100190857_56818435), you can use `root.getChildren().addAll(nodes)`. The `ObservableList` interface adds an [`#addAll(E...)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html#addAll(E...)) method.

Comment: Along with what @Slaw mentioned, you could create an overloaded `baseGUI()` method that accepts a `VBox`: `private void baseGUI(VBox root, Node... nodes)`. From there, configure the VBox and pass it (and the `nodes`) to your other `baseGUI()` method by casting the `VBox` as a `Pane`: `baseGUI(((Pane) root), nodes);`

Comment: That way you can still pass any `Pane` to `baseGUI()` and if its a `VBox`, the appropriate method is called to configure it first. Java will attempt to call the "most specific" overloaded method first, hence passing a `VBox` to `baseGUI()` will call the method that accepts a `VBox` before the one accepting a `Pane`.

Comment: Your current solution is definitely not ideal.

Comment: What will happen if you throw a BorderPane into your function? Hint: you should not add child nodes via getChildren() to BorderPanes.